# How can i stop C# console applications from closing automatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, console-application

How can i stop C# console applications from closing automatically ? [image]

Comment: Write `Console.ReadLine()` in the end

Comment: instead F5 press Ctrl+F5

Comment: Thank you so much im newbie :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last of your code add this

```
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Accept my answer if this help you